# How to resolve the error in java : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException in an online compiler

Tags: java

I have written a simple code to read a 2d integer array of size n1 and n2 and print the middle element in java.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n1=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int n2=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int[][] arr=new int[n1][n2];
        System.out.println("n1"+n1+"n2="+n2);
        String[] sarr=new String[n2];
        for(int i=0;i<n1;i++) {
            sarr = br.readLine().split(" ");//line 13
            for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
                arr[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(sarr[j]);
        }
        System.out.println(arr[n1/2][n2/2]);
    }
}
```

I was getting the below error in an online compiler but when executed in intellijIDEA there was no error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

Comment: If you are getting this error in an online compiler, it probably means that it has some limitations. You are reading something from System.in, which is probably not supported properly there.

Comment: A `readLine()` call will return `null` when you get to the end of the file.

Comment: @rapasoft To be able to get to line 13 means it does support some input, else `int n1=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine())` would throw. Looks like OP did not define enough input data

Comment: @Michael true, but if he used the same input in Intellij IDEA where it works for him (which I suppose he did), it might be the problem with that environment. Anyhow, without additional inputs it's hard to tell.

Comment: I think you got NumberFormatException in line 13.

Comment: @SadmanSobhan no, just no. What gives you that impression?

Comment: This code won't work in IntelliJ either because at `arr[i][j] = ...` you will certainly run into problems because you never initialized `arr[i]`.

Comment: @luk2302 it worked perfectly in intellijIDEA

Comment: You have hadcoded the size String[] sarr=new String[3]; this should be equal to the number of rows

Comment: @UmeshSanwal I just checked by placing it manually even though i gave n2=3 as input

Comment: @SadmanSobhan No I got the above error.

Comment: @StephenC I did not understand correctly what you said

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me. Can you paste your input

Comment: Thanks everyone for your valuable time. I have found out that there was an error in the online compiler while taking the input . in sample test cases they mentioned the sample test cases are in format

Comment: 5 5\n
1 2 3 4 5\n
6 7 8 9 10\n
1 2 3 4 5\n
6 7 8 9 10\n
1 1 1 1 1\n

Comment: but in hidden test cases they took in another format

Comment: 3\n
3\n
6 7 9 -7 -4 -3 -4 -3 -2\n

Comment: Thanks @UmeshSanwal i understood.

Comment: What I said means this:  "If readLine() returns null *then* you are at the end of file".  >>Your<< task would be to figure out why you are at the end of file when your code doesn't expect that.